# Divide the data of array to two arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

I’m getting a series of data from a json like it

```
   [
  {
   "name": "david",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sara",
    "gender": "Female"
  },
  {
    "name": "Philipp",
    "gender": "Male"
  },
  {
    "name": "Marry",
    "gender": "Female"
  }
]
```

I get this data and store them into one array

Lets call it `names`

Now I want to create two other arrays

```
femaleNames

maleNames
```

And I want to save all the female name in `femaleNames` and all the male names in `maleNames` based on the gender type of data.
I don’t that how I can implement this condition in swift 5. Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want just the names or do you want just the "people" of different genders split out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a model struct for your data along these lines:

```
enum Gender: Decodable, String {
    case female = "Female"
    case male = "Male"
}

struct NameEntry: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let gender: Gender
}
```

and given a bunch of names in

```
var names: [NameEntry]
```

your can filter easily using

```
let femaleNames = names.filter { $0.gender == .female }
let maleNames = names.filter { $0.gender == .male }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter over the array;

```swift
struct YourStruct: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let gender: String
}

let femaleNames = names.filter( { $0.gender == "Female"})
let maleNames = names.filter( { $0.gender == "Male"})
```

Comment: Might want to include a note in there about assuming that you've got the arrays encoded to some sort of struct/class that have a `gender` and maybe a `name` property on them.

Comment: Thank you so much, but how I can say if it’s male do that or if it’s female do that?

Comment: You should decode your JSON data to a struct and then using filter. I update it and add struct